# Only populating last row from parse.com table in my tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am hoping someone can help with what I have done wrong :)
I have a query that retrieves data from Parse.com.

After some struggles I have that now working and in the target output I can see all results and I have the correct count of objects.

My problem is now I am populating my tableview but only the "last" entry is in the tableview.
I have tried the reloadData in multiple locations but no luck :(

Would appreciate any help if possible.
Thanks in advance

```
 var TopicPassed:String!
var storedsentences=[getsentences]()

@IBOutlet weak var sentencetableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    navlabel.text = TopicPassed

    var query = PFQuery(className:"TalkToMeSentences")
    query.whereKey("Topic", equalTo:TopicPassed)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // query successful - display number of rows found
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) sentences")



            // print sentences found
            for object in objects {

                let retrievedsentences = object["Sentence"] as NSString
                self.storedsentences = [getsentences(parsesentence: "\(retrievedsentences)")]
                println("\(retrievedsentences) ")
                //self.sentencetableview.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
                //self.sentencetableview.reloadData()

            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
        }
        //self.sentencetableview.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.sentencetableview.reloadData()
    }
    //self.sentencetableview.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    //sentencetableview.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop `for object in objects` you are setting the value of `self.storedsentences` each time. At the end of the loop, it will only contain the last value.

Rather, you want to add each item to the array, not replace the array.